# Oracle PL/SQL - Loop value as dynamic column name without dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, loops, dynamic, plsql, sql-update

I would like to update multiple tables that have the same column name with the same value, instead of having an update for each table, and since Oracle doesn't provide a way to update multiple tables at once I though of using a loop for this.

I tried this but it doesn't work as expected:

```sql
begin
  for i in (select column_value from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('tab1', 'tab2'))) loop
    update i set my_col = 'my value';
  end loop;
end;
```

I know I can use dynamic SQL for this with `execute immediate` but is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Easy answer: NO.

Comment: This seems weird, why do you want the same value to be stored in multiple tables for all of their rows? It seems like this is the wrong way to go about whatever problem you're really having.

Comment: @AndrewSayer It's not for all of the rows, the example code I provided is highly simplified. In real case there's a `where` clause that says which row to update.

Comment: Okay, you can use your SQL to generate SQL, you don't have to use execute immediate or dbms_sql to run it - you would just: spool out a script, review it by eye, run it manually. Is that what you're after or are you actually wanting it to execute itself (in which case you have to use dynamic SQL).

Comment: @AndrewSayer I'm trying to avoid using dynamic SQL, that's why I'm asking this question. I know I can use dynamic SQL and it will work, but I prefer not to, and I imagine that there is a better way to do it that I don't know about.

Comment: @user5507535 It's good to avoid too much dynamic SQL, but avoiding it all together can lead to other problems. It might help to learn a few tricks for handling dynamic SQL that I've explained in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37984068/409172).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question (and so the problem) looks pretty simple:

> update multiple tables that have the same column name with the same value

How about creating a view based on those tables & an `instead of` trigger which would do the job? Here's how:

Sample tables:

```
SQL> select * from tab_a;

        ID M
---------- -
         1 x
         2 y

SQL> select * from tab_b;

NA MY_
-- ---
LF www
JW zzz
MC
```

View:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_tabs as
  2    select to_char(id) idn, my_col from tab_a
  3    union all
  4    select name           , my_col from tab_b;

View created.

SQL> select * from v_tabs;

IDN                                      MY_
---------------------------------------- ---
1                                        x
2                                        y
LF                                       www
JW                                       zzz
MC
```

*Instead of* trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_tabs
  2    instead of update on v_tabs
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    update tab_a set my_col = :new.my_col;
  6    update tab_b set my_col = :new.my_col;
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> update v_tabs set my_col = 'e';

5 rows updated.

SQL> select * from tab_a;

        ID M
---------- -
         1 e
         2 e

SQL> select * from tab_b;

NA MY_
-- ---
LF e
JW e
MC e

SQL>
```

All `MY_COL` values, in all tables involved, are set to `e`. That's what you asked for, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `execute immediate` try with the `DBMS_SQL` package:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#i996963

Here is a syntyax sample of how to use this package taken from the doc:

```plsql
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE demo(salary IN NUMBER) AS
        cursor_name INTEGER;
        rows_processed INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        cursor_name := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
        DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cursor_name, 'DELETE FROM emp WHERE sal > :x', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
        DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(cursor_name, ':x', salary);
        rows_processed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cursor_name);
        DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);
    END;
    /
```